# How do I @extend external CSS classes in a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, sass

For example, if I have something like this in my component:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.color-blue {
  color: blue;
}

.orange-blue {
  @extend .color-blue; // This works!
  @extend .bg-orange; // .bg-orange is defined in another css file somewhere. This doens't work
}
</style>
```

I get an error that says

> ".orange-blue" failed to @extend ".bg-orange".
>
> The selector ".bg-orange" was not found.

I've read that I can add

```
@import 'path/to/orange.css'
```

to my style block, but that doesn't seem to do the trick here. Also, wouldn't that result in the CSS being repeated for every component that imports it?

Answer (score 1):

Import the file with other styles like that

> 

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>  
 @import '~styles/mixins';  

... 

</style>
```

or use the usual path

```
@import '../../../styles/mixins';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way:

Create the file containing the class you want to extend:

```
src/styles/style.scss

.my_class_to_extend {
  backgroud-color: aqua;
}
```

In your vue.config.js file you add the following pointing to your file:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "@/styles/style.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After that you can extend in your vue component without problems:

```
...
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.my_extended_class {
  @extend .my_class_to_extend;
}
```

Note that to use that you need scss files all along, not css.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can not extend css class in `*.scss` file by importing plain `*.css` file. Scss compiler will throw an error `SassError: The target selector was not found`.

The easy way is to rename referenced *.css file to *.scss. So outcome would be like `@import 'path/to/orange.scss'`